# Head remains null after pushing several nodes into linked list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list

```
class node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.data = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class linkedlist {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    push = (val) => {
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = new node(val);
            return;
        }
        let temp = new node(val);
        temp.next = this.head;
        this.head = temp;
    }

    print = () => {
        while (this.head) {
            console.log(this.head.data);
            this.head = this.head.next;
        }
    }
}

var ll = new linkedlist();
var n = 5;
while (n--) ll.push(n);

ll.print(); // 0 1 2 3 4

console.log(ll.head); // null
```

Why is `head` still null? Is it because I used `let` to declare class variables?

Does `head` have to be of global scope in order for me to modify its value? And why did the `print` function work just fine when `head`'s still null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print function is incrementing the **head** till it is null, so when you check the value of **head** after you call **print**, it will always give **null**. Always initialise temporary variable to **head** and use that to iterate like below so as keep the reference to the list.

```
  print = () => {
    let pointer = this.head;
    while (pointer) {
      console.log(pointer.data);
      pointer = pointer.next;
    }
  };
```